# Swift: how to set function type value to optional variable?

Tags: ios, function, swift, variables, optional-parameters

I want to use function as a completion for another function, when it's needed. But I have a trouble that best described with code:

```
...{
   var myCompletion : (() -> Void)? = nil
   if condition {
       myCompletion = myCompletionFunction() // <==========problem here
   }
   someMethodThatCouldHaveCompletion(myCompletion)
   ...
}

func someMethodThatCouldHaveCompletion(completion: (() -> Void)?){
...
}

func myCompletionFunction() {
...
}
```

I have an error: `Cannot assign a value of type '()' to a value of type '(()->Void)?'`

I tried to add `as! (() -> Void)?` after setting function to myCompletion variable, but receive another error `Cannot downcast from '()' to a more optional type '(()->Void)?'`

So, is there a way to solve it? I have a sense that I miss something with `completion: (() -> Void)?` type.

Comment: Do you need the () after myCompletionFunction?  Aren't you assigning the function to myCompletion rather than the return value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `myCompletion` is fine, the problem is here:

```
myCompletion = myCompletionFunction()
```

You aren't assigning `myCompletion` to `myCompletionFunction`; you're calling `myCompletionFunction` and assigning it's return value to `myCompletion`, causing the type mismatch.

Change that line to:

```
myCompletion = myCompletionFunction
```

Comment: @JoshGafni oh thanks guys, you are right, stupid mistake

Comment: @flinth I don't think it's a stupid mistake. I think it's a poorly worded error message. It's a good candidate for an automatic "fix it" suggestion too.

Comment: Right.  It helps to know that `()` is the same as `Void`.